# What are the proper steps for changing or swapping out Service Workers in Production?

Tags: angular, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

I have a PWA built in Angular that is **in production** and is using the sw-precache service worker. This was before Angular had the `@angular/pwa` package. If I wanted to switch over and start using the Angular sw instead how would I go about doing this?

Programmatically I would need to handle this for the users. I would think I need to get registered SWs, check for the name of the old SW, unregister it, (purge cache?), and then register the new one. Is it that simple? I feel like with service workers and dealing with caches there's going to be some gotchas. I have yet to find an actual example of this process however.

Any code examples would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you just remove old manifest reference from index.html and run `ng add @angular/pwa` which adds a new one, wouldn't that be enough (for the app to use the new one)?

Comment: My use case here is handling this in a already live production state where the users already have a running sw with a cache. What you're suggesting might work in a local dev environment or for new users but for current end users changing the manifest doesn't remove the running sw those users already have on their browser.

Comment: By default, Angular CLI doesnt add service worker to dev environment, though I dont think there would be a difference (you can start app in http server and test it locally). What I ment to say is that if your index.html points to a new worker, that worker should be used by your app. While the old worker, would remain, but wouldnt be used. Just thinking loud here

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to make sure that you "de-register" the old service-worker. If you add @angular/pwa through the schematics, they also create a file called `safety-worker.js` for you, which in their documentation is used for exactly that purpose: when you want to remove an old SW, you can use that file by simply renaming `safety-worker.js` to whatever your sw-precache worker's name was. This file could also include instructions for removing the old cache (which you'd need to add yourself). The documentation for the safety-worker can be found [in the official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-devops#safety-worker).

You can already update the manifest file with the new reference to `ngsw-worker.js`, since after removal of the old SW, when the page is next visited, the new SW will be installed and take over on subsequent visits.

Comment: Thank you! This is good to know. However, is there a way to configure the safety-worker.js path to the old sw url from the angular.json config or programiatically somehow? Manually changing it in the `/www` folder after a `--prod` build will definitely be too cumbersome.

Comment: Also is there a code example for removing old cache after implementing this? There are no instructions in the safety-worker file but looks like I could do the cache removal after the returned unregister promise in the saftey-worker.js file but again that would have to be added manually every time I do a --prod build.

Answer (score 0):

Check this recommended recipe for your Service Worker. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/advanced-recipes#offer_a_page_reload_for_users. So you can notify your users that there is a new Service Worker available and they can get it. Hope it will help you.